# What is the proper terminology for the process of a satellite entering a planet's shadow?

Tags: artificial-satellite, spacecraft, terminology

What is the proper terminology for when a satellite or spaceship passes into a planet's shadow or night side? Is it crossing the terminator? Passing into eclipse (or something better)? If there is a different name for coming back into the light, what would that be as well?

Comment: This was the better site to ask, but now that you have an answer on this question in [Astronomy SE](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/34514/7982) it's best to close this or delete it. You didn't know it yet, but cross-posting questions (same questions on multiple sites) is strongly discouraged in Stack Exchange because it leads to fragmentation of answers (good answers spread out over multiple sites). Now that that question has an answer, the only way to get it here is to close it in Astronomy and then have migrated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is crossposted from Astronomy SE where an answer exists already. Best to close (or delete) this and migrate that one.

Comment: @uhoh How do I go about migrating it from there?

Comment: I think people mostly say that " the satellite is in eclipse "

Comment: @Adham That's good for already being on the night side, but what about the actual transition point? Would someone aboard the ISS say "We are crossing into/out of eclipse?"

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is crossposted

Comment: @Trevortni there are currently three votes to close here, if you can add your own vote (I'm not sure if you can yet) that can also help speed things up. Thanks!

Comment: @uhoh What would I click on to do that if I can?

Comment: @Trevortni the page looks different depending on your current reputation (points) If you can see the `close` option as it's shown in this screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/osMlj.png then click it and choose the "off-topic" option and click a few more things to confirm as shown in this screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/2TNZI.png Thank you for your help and participation! Stack Exchange is a little different than most other sites, but once you get used to it everything will make more sense.

Comment: @uhoh It suddenly occurred to me to check my other sites. It looks like I have that permission in Worldbuilding and Stack, but not Role-playing, so it must be between 177 and 358. The 100 free points starting on a new site aren't enough. I've never had reason to look for that before.